# Separar Tabelas em Colunas utilizando HTML

Tags: html

Preciso distribuir 10 tabelas em 2 colunas de 5 para exibição.

Como posso fazer essa distribuição ou então separar as tabelas do exemplo abaixo por um espaço ou algo similar?

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font: 75%/1.6 "Myriad Pro", Frutiger, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 35em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
thead {
  background: #ccc url(https://www.devfuria.com.br/html-css/tabelas/bar.gif) repeat-x left center;
  border-top: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color:#3d80df;
  color: #fff;
}
thead tr:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #edf5ff;
}
th {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.1em 1em;
}
</style>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <table id="Programa1">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Desculpe, Não entendi sua pergunta, poderia explicar?

Comment: Você só quer deixar as tabelas separadas umas das outras?

Comment: Eu preciso exibir 10 tabelas, quero exibir 5 do lado esquerdo e 5 do lado direito. Basicamente seria isso.

Comment: O método que for mais fácil, o que consegui até agora é deixar elas lado a lado, mas ai elas ficam grudadas, daí se der para separar com um espaço já resolve meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse código fazem tabelas responsivas, que se encaixam na tela dos telefones celulares!

**Entendendo:**

Criamos a classe .divTab que tem um tamanho de 50% da tela de qualquer dispositivo, a tabela vai ficar com o wdt de 95% para pegar as margens e ficar separada.

```
.divTab{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
table {
  margin: 5px !important;
  width:95%;
  margin: 5px !important;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

Aqui a gente define a resolução do telefone celular ou tablet, para as tabelas ficarem responsivas.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .divTab{
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  }
  table {
  width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font: 75%/1.6 "Myriad Pro", Frutiger, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.divTab{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
table {
  margin: 5px !important;
  width:95%;
  margin: 5px !important;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
thead {
  background: #ccc url(https://www.devfuria.com.br/html-css/tabelas/bar.gif) repeat-x left center;
  border-top: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color:#3d80df;
  color: #fff;
}
thead tr:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #edf5ff;
}
th {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.1em 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .divTab{
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  }
  table {
  width:100%;
}
}
</style>
    <div class="divTab">
        <table id="Programa1">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div><div class="divTab" >
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div><div class="divTab" >
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<div class="divTab" >
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>

<div class="divTab" >
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th></th> 
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Para o momento não é necessário uma função responsiva, os primeiros exemplos já suprem minha necessidade. Mas muito obrigado, gostei muito da dica e tenho certeza que será muito útil em outros projetos. Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode usar `display:flex` em um *container* pai das `divs` que vão estar com a table dentro, assim vc deixa a table com 100% da largura dessa `div`, sendo que a `div` que vai ter a table dentro tem 50% da largura do pai, assim vc vai ter 2 colunas de 50% no *container* pai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Só fiz o ajuste das colunas as de mias coisas do CSS não mexi, e tirando o *container* pai não inclui nada no seu HTML, mas lembre-se de mudar o nome dos `IDs` de cada tabela quando for editar o conteúdo

**EDITE:** Inclui uma table que ocupa 100% da largura do *container*. Para isso criei uma classe `w100` com `width` de 100% e coloquei na `div` .box.

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font: 75%/1.6 "Myriad Pro", Frutiger, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}

thead {
    background: #ccc url(https://www.devfuria.com.br/html-css/tabelas/bar.gif) repeat-x left center;
    border-top: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #3d80df;
    color: #fff;
}

thead tr:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #edf5ff;
}

th {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
    padding: 0.1em 1em;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 50%;
}
.box.w100 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<div class="box w100">
        <table id="Programa2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Programa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Saude</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, acredito que isso já deva resolver meu problema. Agora vou acertar os nomes e atribuir as funcionalidades. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani sem problemas meu caro, boa sorte com o projeto. Depois se vc achar que alguma pergunta resolveu o seu problema lembrese de marca-la como aceita nesse ícone  `✔` ao lado das setinhas da pergunta que vc escolher. []´s

Comment: Bom dia, vou utilizar o exemplo do container, porém me surgiu uma dúvida, para o caso de eu inserir fora desse layout mais uma tabela, essa consumindo toda a tela, abaixo dessas 10 já realizadas, seria possível? Talvez necessite mudar o CSS?

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani é bem tranquilo, basta vc criar um classe assim `.w100 {width:100%}` ai vc coloca essa class na div box, ficaria assim: `<div class="box w100">`. Dessa forma essa tabela fica com 100% da largura. Testa ai e qq coisa me fala

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar, a tabela permanece com 50%. Inseri na última linha do CSS: }
.w100 {
 width:100%
}
</style>
    <div class="box w100">
        <table id="Programa1">.... (Restante da tabela)

Comment: No caso meu box está referenciando 50%, talvez o que eu deva fazer seria criar mais duas classes? uma 50% e uma 100% e referenciar para cada tabela qual quero utilizar? Vou fazer alguns testes aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani fiz um **EDITE** na resposta, da uma lida lá, tb já atualizei o código com o exemplo funcionando e um box com 100% de largura

Comment: Muito obrigado, Eu ainda não estou conseguindo incluir isso no código que estava utilizando, mas com o exemplo que você postou funcionou, vou me basear nele e efetuar as demais alterações. Agradeço novamente a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Para **separar** as tabelas **em um espaço X na horizontal**, você pode colocar um `DIV` no meio dos outros dois `DIV`s existentes. Veja o exemplo abaixo onde tomei X por `2.5em`:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <table id="Programa1">
    ...
</div>

<div style="float: left; padding: 2.5em;"></div>

<div style="float:left;">
...
```

Fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deste modo, não precisa se preocupar com espaçamentos nos `DIV`s que importam. Não vai afetar o tamanho posterior e o cálculo final fica fácil.

Comment: Essa eu havia tentado mas não tinha dado certo. Devo ter errado na sintaxe, Vou tentar novamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Deu certo também dessa forma. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani tem que usar `padding` já que `width` é expansível com o conteúdo. E por ter zero de conteúdo, o `width` efetivo fica 0. Pode ser que seja nisso que tenha tido problema ao tentar previamente antes da pergunta.

Comment: Entendi, Muito obrigado novamente.